# Filter model on filtered reverse_set length in Django

Tags: django

I have models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    bar = models.IntegerField()  # Or any other field

class C(models.Model):
```

I need to filter A by length of c_set of b filtered by value of C.bar. Now I have:

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    if len(a.b.c_set.filter(bar=1234)) == 0:
        continue
    # Code for needed 'a'
```

How can I filter 'A' with only one database request? I have other filters for 'A' and I need to combine them with new one. Something like this:

```
A.objects.annotate(newfilter=Count(b__c_set__bar=1234)).filter(**{
    'newfilter__gt': 0,
    # My filters
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A.objects.filter(b__c__bar=1234).distinct().filter(**{
    # My filters
})
```

Comment: Seems it works! Thanks a lot. But with a small change: A.objects.filter(b__c_set__bar=1234).distinct().filter(**{...})